# Can the Liquid Ruby template engine deal with Rails forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, liquid, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been searching for a template engine to allow users to create lessons and exercises online easily.
Seems like [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/) is the most popular for use in Rails. Can Liquid users easily create rails forms?

Normally I create forms in ERB with:

```
<%= form_for(@lesson) do |f| %>
  <% if @lesson.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@lesson.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this lesson from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @lesson.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div>lots of fields</div>
<% end %>
```

Rails will automatically insert the CSRF protection stuff among other things. Can I do the same with Liquid? Can I create filters, tags and/or blocks in Liquid to emulate Rails form tags?

Answer (score 2):

You can register your own tag blocks with Liquid, but it doesn't came out of the box.

If you check the [documentation](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/wiki/Liquid-for-Programmers), you will notice that you can create your own tag blocks.

You can register your own tag block

```
class LiquidForm < Liquid::Block
  def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
     super
  end

  def render(context)
    form_tag("/hello_word") do 
      input_tag "hello"
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('liquid_form', LiquidForm)
```

And then parse the text you want with liquid

```
text = " {% liquid_form %} Form content {% endliquid_form %} "
@template = Liquid::Template.parse(text)
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete, how do you get the csrf functionality to work?

Comment: Actually it is complete, have you readed and tried the code? form_tag will render the csrf token within a form, and you can call form_tag from a liquid template. Let me know once you try the code and you check that it doesn't work as expected, so I can help you to debug the issue.

Comment: I have tried the code and it does'nt work for me. I Started this question a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715490/rails-form-block-in-helper-how-do-i-include-protect-from-forgery/24766459?noredirect=1#comment38834460_24766459 but it stranded. Do you know if I need to add the controller in a different way or do you use a gem other than the liquid gem? How do you call the render method in your applicaiton?

Comment: I'll check it out and get a sample project working for you today :)