# Rails Form block in helper - How do i include "Protect from forgery"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, liquid, csrf-protection

I'm trying to build a form block for my liquid theme language. I have based my approach on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189669/can-the-liquid-ruby-template-engine-deal-with-rails-forms). How ever the answer seems to be incomplete.

The problem is that protect from forgery and some other methods are unavailable. Causing an error:

```
Liquid error: undefined method `protect_against_forgery?' for #
```

This is my code:

```
   class LiquidFormTag < Liquid::Block

        include ActionView::Context
        include ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper

        def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)

            super
        end

        def render(context)
            form_tag("#") do

                super
            end
        end
    end

    Liquid::Template.register_tag('liquid_form', LiquidFormTag)
```

Does any one know how i add the `protect_against_forgery` method do this class?

**Edit:** this is the error output:
[image]

**Edit 2:**

This is the relevant part of my Liquid code:

```
{% ticket_form %}
    {% for offer in event.offers %}

        <div class="well well-sm">  
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-5 col-md-6 col-lg-7">
                    <h5>{{offer.name}}</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-5 pull-right">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">{{offer.price}}</span>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control tickets-count" cols="2" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="0">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    {% endfor %}
{% endticket_form %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree to Rodrigo but it will be hard to identify method names that will be deleagated to controller.

That's why I prefer to extend  `Liquid::Block` class and delegate missing methods to controller if responds..

```
class LiquidFormTag < Liquid::Block
  include ActionView::Context
  include ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper

  attr_reader :controller

  def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
    super
  end

  def render(context)
    @controller = context.registers[:controller]
    form_tag('#') do
      super(context).html_safe
    end
  end

end


Liquid::Block.class_eval do
  # This delegates missing - including private & protected - methods (like protect_against_forgery?) to controller.
  def method_missing(*args)
    begin
      if controller.respond_to?(args.first, true)
        controller.send(args.first)
      else
        super
      end
    rescue
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The method `protect_against_forgery` came from `ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection` module. But include this module in class `Liquid::Block` doesn't seems to be a good practice.

The solution I use is:

```
class LiquidFormTag < Liquid::Block
  include ActionView::Context
  include ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper

  attr_reader :controller

  def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens)
    super
  end

  def render(context)
    @controller = context.registers[:controller]
    form_tag('#') do
      super(context).html_safe
    end
  end

  delegate :form_authenticity_token, :request_forgery_protection_token, :protect_against_forgery?, to: :controller

end

Liquid::Template.register_tag 'liquid_form', LiquidFormTag
```

To this code work, you need to provide current controller to Liquid render method:

```
class OffersController < ApplicationController

   def create
      @offer = Offer.new
      Liquid::Template.parse(template).render 'offer' => @offer, registers: {controller: self}
   end

end
```

Comment: Nice! almost there. Now the only problem is that the form content is rendered weird. There is allot of t\r\n \r\n \r\n in the output. It says that :controller is nil.

Comment: Yes. However the liquid block class might be blocking it? or do you use this inside a liquid block as well? Also is there any way i can test if the attr_reader works?

Comment: Please, update your answer with your Form class and liquid code

Comment: What do you mean with Form class? Do you mean the the place the the Offer model for example?

Comment: Also note: i have written the code exacly like your answer, so if :controller is supposed to be the class controller I'm building the class for then that might be the error.

Comment: @OleHenrikSkogstrøm, I using this gem: https://github.com/imaboldcompany/liquid_renderer. This gem [calls](https://github.com/imaboldcompany/liquid_renderer/blob/master/lib/liquid_renderer/renderer.rb#L18) `render` method with `:registers` (used by `LiquidFormTag`). If you rendering the template by hand, you should include `:registers` hash with the controller. Ex: `template.render(your_vars: example, registers: {controller: your_controller})`

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm almost there, just not sure what to set as "your_controller". I have tried to pass the OffersController class inn, but it does not seem to work. Can you maybe show me an example of this too?

Comment: Hi, thank you. Now it seems like the variable controller is just #. the error i get is "Liquid error: protected method `protect_against_forgery?' called for #"

Comment: This is killing me! Why can't i access the controller with attr_reader: :controller? Do i need to define :controller somewhere? Please help me!

Comment: @OleHenrikSkogstrøm, I don't know what you doing wrong. [Here](https://github.com/imaboldcompany/liquid_renderer/blob/master/lib%2Fliquid_renderer%2Frenderer.rb#L18), I provide the controller to render method inside the `:registers` hash. Please, take a detailed look, it can help you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem this days, and I solved this way:

```
class LiquidForm < Liquid::Block
  include ActionView::Context
  include ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper

  attr_reader :csrf_token

  def initialize(tag_name, markup, options)
   super
   @model = markup.strip
  end

  def render(context)
    csrf = context.registers[:csrf_token]

    form_tag "/new_obj", authenticity_token: false do
      "#{hidden_field_tag('authenticity_token', csrf)}
       #{super(context)}".html_safe
    end

  end
end
```

Now I needed to generate the security token from my App. I investigated that inside the `form_tag` I could called the method `form_authenticity_token` that is available from the `ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection` module. [Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085136/how-to-generate-authenticitytoken-on-rails).

This `form_authenticity_token` only creates a secure random key, you can see it in [form_authenticity_token](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/form_authenticity_token)

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb, line 249
  def form_authenticity_token
    session[:_csrf_token] ||= SecureRandom.base64(32)
  end
```

As we cannot call this inside our `LiquidForm` class. We need to generate the token manually exactly like this method in our Liquid render method. This can be in your view or controller. Example:

```
=Liquid::Template.parse(template).render('offer' => @offer, registers: {:csrf_token => session[:_csrf_token] ||= SecureRandom.base64(32)})
```